# Uniform convergence of series $\sum x/(n^p + x^2n^q)$ for $p > 1$ and $q \leq 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Although a source tells me that the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x}{n^p + x^2 n^q}$ is not uniformly convergent for $p > 1$ and $q \leq 0$ on any interval $\left[ a, b \right]$, I have tried the following:-

We have

$$\left| \dfrac{x}{n^p + x^2 n^q} \right| = \left| \dfrac{n^{-q} x}{n^{p - q} + x^2} \right| \leq \dfrac{n^{-q} \left| x \right|}{n^{p - q}} \leq \dfrac{\max \left\lbrace \left| a \right|, \left| b \right| \right\rbrace}{n^p}$$

Now, the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\max \left\lbrace \left| a\ \right|, \left| b \right| \right\rbrace}{n^p}$ is convergent for $p > 1$ so that the original series is uniformly convergent by Wiestrauss M test.

Is this proof correct and the answer from the source wrong? Or is there a mistake in the proof?

Comment: Your work seems fine to me

Comment: Your argument is right but you made it a little more complicated than necessary. You could have simply dropped $x^{2}n^{q}$ directly to get the bound $\frac {|x|} {n^{p}}$.

Comment: your solution is right. Uniform convergence can probably be improved in this case to $x>0$. See this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4427079/121671)